# Autocomplete with Angular and RXJS

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6, angular2-observables

New to RXJS and trying to figure out how to setup my autocomplete. 
Right now I have a `typeahead` component that handles the `input` element and emits the value ('term'). 
In my `filters` component (parent) I handle the logic of making api calls and dealing with the data (via a service). I have a function in this component that is called with the `term` change and makes an api call. Having trouble setting this up with some of the examples I saw, namely switchMap seems to be needed to make the correct calls. 
Basically the function should do 2 things: 1. Send requests to the api and handle the return data.
2. Push that into a list that will be display as autocomplete options. 
Right now it looks like this but there is a syntax error:

```
public IdTypeahead(term: string) {
    this.model.NctIdList = [];

    if (!(term && term.length > 0)) {
      return;
    }

    this.searchCriteria.nctIdPrefix = term;
    this.searchCriteria.aggregateOn = 'nctid';
    // this.NctIdList = of(term)
    let input$ = of(term)
      .switchMap(() => from(this.filterService.GetNctIdFilterData(this.searchCriteria))
          .subscribe((result: any) => {
            this.NctIdList.push(result.nctid)
              return result.nctid
          }

          )
  }
```

Previously it looked like this, but was making the wrong calls (calls were lagging):

```
public IdTypeahead(term: string) {
    this.model.NctIdList = [];

    if (!(term && term.length > 0)) {
      return;
    }

    this.searchCriteria.nctIdPrefix = term;
    this.searchCriteria.aggregateOn = 'nctid';
    this.NctIdList = 
    this.filterService.GetNctIdFilterData(this.searchCriteria).pipe(
    map((result: any) => result.nctid) as Observable<string[]>
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you should do -

```
export class YourComponent implements OnInit {

  listToShowInAutoComplete$: Observable<string>;
  serachTerm$: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject<string>(null);

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.listToShowInAutoComplete$ = this.serachTerm$.pipe(
                                        debounceTime(200),
                                        distinctUntilChanged(),
                                        filter(t => !!t),
                                        switchMap(term => {
                                          this.searchCriteria.nctIdPrefix = term;
                                          this.searchCriteria.aggregateOn = 'nctid';
                                          return this.filterService.GetNctIdFilterData(this.searchCriteria);
                                        }),
                                        map(result => {
                                          //i am assuming that result is your list which is to be shown in the autocomplete options
                                          //adjust this code as per your api response
                                          //idea here is to project the result to the items to be shown in autocomplete
                                          return result;
                                        })
                                    );
  }

  IdTypeahead(term: string) {
    this.serachTerm$.next(term);
  }

}
```

now you should bind listToShowInAutoComplete$ in your template like this -

```
<your-auto-complete-comp [yourPropery]="listToShowInAutoComplete$ | async"></your-auto-complete-comp>
```

Import required constructs as needed.
Hope this will give you an idea of how to implement typeahead. Adjust your filter logic as per your business need.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest first setup subject which is responsible for term changes and based on that execute whatever you require. As I understand your use case I would suggest:

```
  import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
  import { takeUntil, switchMap, filter, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

  private term$ = new Subject<string>();

  // execute setup only once, for example in ngOnInit()
  private setup() {
    this.term$
      .pipe(
        filter((term) => term && term.length > 0),
        tap((term) => {
          this.model.NctIdList = [];
          this.searchCriteria.nctIdPrefix = term;
          this.searchCriteria.aggregateOn = 'nctid';
        }),
        switchMap((_) =>
          this.filterService.GetNctIdFilterData(this.searchCriteria),
        ),
      )
      .subscribe((result: any) => {
        this.NctIdList.push(result.nctid);
      });
  }

  public IdTypeahead(term: string) {
    this.term$.next(term);
  }
```